# Filling NAs with a dataframe merge

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame `c` like this

```
c
             Freq      CTM
000110100111    2       NA
110110100111    1 32.58847
111001011000    2       NA
111111111111    1 25.61041
```

and a data frame `nona_c` like this

```
   nona_c 
             Freq     CTM
000110100111    2 37.0642
111001011000    2 37.0642
```

I want to replace the NAs in the `CTM` column of `c` with the CTM values of `nona_c`. The rownames of `nona_c` (the binary strings) will always exist in `c`.

The output should be

```
mergedC
             Freq      CTM
000110100111    2  37.0642
110110100111    1 32.58847
111001011000    2  37.0642
111111111111    1 25.61041
```

I've been trying `merge` without success here.

```
mergedC  <- merge(x = c, y = nona_c, by = 0, #rownames
    all.y = TRUE)
```

Comment: as a side note; it's strange to see an object called `c`, particularly given the `?c` function. May cause issues down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `match` operation might make this more straightforward:

```
c$CTM[is.na(c$CTM)] <- nona_c$CTM[match(rownames(c)[is.na(c$CTM)], rownames(nona_c))]

#             Freq      CTM           id
#000110100111    2 37.06420 000110100111
#110110100111    1 32.58847 110110100111
#111001011000    2 37.06420 111001011000
#111111111111    1 25.61041 111111111111
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table` using a join `on` the variable of interest.  Here we are joining on the row name column.  The values of "i.CTM" are assigned (`:=`) to the 'CTM'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(c, keep.rownames=TRUE)[]
setDT(nona_c, keep.rownames=TRUE)[]

c[nona_c, CTM := i.CTM , on = "rn"]
c
#             rn Freq      CTM
#1: 000110100111    2 37.06420
#2: 110110100111    1 32.58847
#3: 111001011000    2 37.06420
#4: 111111111111    1 25.61041
```

NOTE: The row.names are not retained in `data.table` or `dplyr`.  So, while converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', we use the `keep.rownames = TRUE`.